# django.db.utils.DatabaseError: ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

Tags: python, sql, django, oracle, django-oracle

Trying to connect to the Oracle DB via settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.oracle', 
        'NAME': 'Hostname:Port/Service name not SID',  
        'USER': 'Username',                      
        'PASSWORD': 'Password',                                     
    }
}
```

Based on what I have found online, that is supposed to be how I connect to an Oracle DB via service name if I do not have SID. But I still get the error `django.db.utils.DatabaseError: ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified`

If I however forgo placing these details in the `settings.py` and I just use the connection strings provided by `cx_Oracle`,

```
dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn('Hostname', 'Port', 
                             service_name='Service name not SID')
connection = cx_Oracle.connect('Username', 'Password', dsn_tns)
```

I connect just fine. Is there a new syntax to connect to the service name for settings.py? Is there a point in trying to connect via settings.py if I can simply connect via the connection strings?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

settings.py

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

EHS_CONF_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'arquivo.conf')
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': os.environ['DB_ENGINE'],
        'NAME': os.environ['DB_NAME'],
        'HOST': os.environ.get('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'PORT': os.environ.get('DB_PORT', '1521'),
        'USER': os.environ.get('DB_USER', 'user'),
        'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('DB_PASS', "pass")
    }
}
```

arquivo.conf

```
DB_NAME=XE
DB_USER=user
DB_PASS=pass
DB_HOST=10.7.0.140 <-- ip host
DB_PORT=1521
DB_ENGINE=django.db.backends.oracle
```

I had a problem when my password contained '@'